# Script to backup Mysql database onto amazon s3

Tags: backup, mysql, cron, aws, amazon

Can someone explain the script for backing up of Mysql database onto amazon s3?[Script](https://gist.github.com/oodavid/2206527#file-s3mysqlbackup-sh)

Comment: Over ssh . since im new to this field i want to know what the codes in that script does

Comment: There is a line in the script "databases=`mysql -u root -p$mysqlpass -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | tr -d "| " | grep -v "\(Database\|information_schema\|performance_schema\|mysql\|test\)"`When i am executing the db specified in the code are not uploaded onto aws. There is only tar file of phpmyadmin and sys database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bash script for backup MYSQL to S3.

```
SERVERNAME="YOUR_SERVER_NAME"
TIME=`date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M"`             
FILENAME="backup-DB-$SERVERNAME-$TIME.sql.gz"      
DESDIR="/var/backfile"          
mysqldump -u root -pYOURPASSWORD YOURDBNAME | gzip -9 > $DESDIR/$FILENAME
/usr/bin/aws s3 cp $DESDIR/$FILENAME s3://YOURS3BucketName
/bin/rm $DESDIR/$FILENAME
```

Change SERVERNAME to your server name; this variable used only for creating file name.

Change YOURPASSWORD to your MYSQL password.

Change YOURDBNAME to your MYSQL database name you want to backup

Change YOURS3BucketName to your S3 bucket name.

You must install AWS CLI and configure your AWS cred before using the script.

Finally, put your script in Cron job by

@daily /root/dbback.sh

Answer (score 0):

That script needs you to define root password for you database and you S3 storage's bucket name. So edit it first then try executing it.

That command skips information_schema, performance_schema, mysql & test databases which usually not needed for backup porposes.

I would suggest for you to replicate current setup of your database to a development environment and try that script there.

Comment: I just created a new database and updated the crontab now. It seems whenever a cronjob is executed there should be a mail sent to /var/mail/root but i am not getting anything here. `30 2   * bash /var/www/s3mysqlbackup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1`.@grepmaster

Comment: I'd redirect output to log (/var/log/s3mysqlbqckup.log) and check it.
Also you can check /var/log/crond.log

Comment: Is it necessary to restart crontab after editing it? i am using `crontab -e`, some say to use `/etc/crontab` and restart it after editing using `/etc/crontab restart`.

Comment: No, crond doesn't need to be restarted, but it require newline in the en of cron job.  And seems that you have a few asterisk in you job.

Comment: read about crontab